# Largest Odd Divisor Sum Help

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, let $d(n)$ be the largest odd divisor of $n$. Find the last three digits of the sum $d(1)+d(2)+d(3)+⋯+d(2^{99}).$

I have that the odd terms sum to $2^{196}$ but am stuck on the even terms. Can someone provide a hint or a solution? Thanks.

Comment: what conditions are there on the largest odd divisor maybe that will help you.

Comment: I have edited my post with what I have so far.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee What do you mean by conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$d(2n)=d(n)$$
since $2$ cannot be an odd divisor. Now let us separate your sum into even and odd terms:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^{99}} d(n)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(2n)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(2n-1)$$
and now, since $d(2n)=d(n)$, we have
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(2n-1)$$
Now we can split it up again:
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{2^{97}} d(2n)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{97}} d(2n-1)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(2n-1)$$
or
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{2^{97}} d(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{97}} d(2n-1)+\sum_{n=1}^{2^{98}} d(2n-1)$$
If we continue this process, we end up with
$$=1+\sum_{k=0}^{98}\sum_{n=1}^{2^k}d(2n-1)$$
And since you seem to know how to calculate the sum of odd terms, this sum should be manageable for you.

**EDIT:** I had a bit of a brain fart and didn't realize that 
$$d(2n-1)=2n-1$$
so now we have
$$=1+\sum_{k=0}^{98}\sum_{n=1}^{2^k} 2n-1$$
and since the sum of the first $a$ odd numbers is $a^2$,
$$=1+\sum_{k=0}^{98} (2^k)^2$$
$$=1+\sum_{k=0}^{98} 4^{k}$$
and this is just a geometric sequence that, using the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$
sums to
$$=1+\frac{4^{99}-1}{3}$$
$$=\color{green}{\frac{4^{99}+2}{3}}$$

Can you find the last three digits of this?

Comment: We just add the odd terms using the $n^2$ formula.

Comment: How you find the value though?

Comment: @MathLover Oh yeah, duh. Sorry, I had a brain fart. :P

Comment: @MathLover Sure, I'll finish solving for you.

Comment: No need to give a detailed explanation, it is fine.

Comment: @MathLover Got it! Do you understand my explanation?

Comment: It seems fine. How do we find the last 3 digits?

Comment: @MathLover Ooh, forgot about that part. I'm on it.

Comment: Ok thanks. No need to be way too detailed though.

Comment: @MathLover Okay, I got it... but I'm not going to give it to you. I found the *value* of the sum for you, and now it's time for you to put in a little bit of effort.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MathLover Yep, that's what I got! Nice job! Out of curiosity, what method did you use to get that?

Comment: @MathLover Okay, now I have a challenge for you - can you find the **first** digit?

Comment: I have posted another solution if you're interested.

Comment: It should be $1+\sum_{k=0}^{98}\sum_{n=1}^{2^k} (2n-1)$, not $1+\sum_{k=0}^{98}\sum_{n=1}^{2^k} 2n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

here's how I'd do it ( i'm stupid like that):

1. partial sums of the odd numbers up to n = squares
2. even numbers are 2*x if x is odd then repeat step one using x.
3. repeat 1 and 2 until all steps are done you will get something like

$$\sum_{i=1}^n d(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over2^{i+1}}\rfloor}(2j+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

There's already a correct posted answer. My answer shows another solution.

Hint: for all $n\ge 1$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, $$d(n)=\frac{n}{2^{\upsilon_2(n)}},$$

where $\upsilon_2(n)$ means the exponent of the highest power of $2$ that divides $n$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{99}} d(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{99}} \frac{i}{2^{\upsilon_2(i)}}=$$

$$=\sum_{i|\upsilon_2(i)=0}d(i)+\sum_{i|\upsilon_2(i)=1}d(i)+\cdots+$$

$$+\sum_{i|\upsilon_2(i)=99}d(i)=$$

You can notice that for all $0\le k\le 98$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ we have

$2^k(2(2^{98-k}-1)+1)=2^{99}-2^k<2^{99}$,

$2^k(2(2^{98-k})+1)=2^{99}+2^k>2^{99}$.

$$=\frac{1}{2^0}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2^{98}-1}(2^0(2i+1))\right)+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2^1}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2^{97}-1}(2^1(2i+1))\right)+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2^2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2^{96}-1}(2^2(2i+1))\right)+\cdots+$$

$$+\frac{1}{2^{98}}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2^0-1}(2^{98}(2i+1))\right)+\frac{2^{99}}{2^{99}}=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{2^j-1}(2i+1)\right)+1=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98}\left(2\sum_{i=0}^{2^j-1}(i) + \sum_{i=0}^{2^j-1}(1)\right)+1=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98}\left(2\cdot \frac{(2^j-1)(2^j)}{2}+2^j\right)+1=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98}((2^j-1)(2^j)+2^j)+1=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98}(4^j-2^j+2^j)+1=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{98} (4^j)+1$$

Use the geometric progression sum formula.

[As WolframAlpha suggests, the answer is $782$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7B98%7D+(4%5Ej)%2B1+mod+1000)

The answer is the same if you use the method given by another answerer. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((4%5E99%2B2)%2F3)+mod+1000